# Access variable from object in array in the angularJS code

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I am a newby to typescript and angularJS and I created a class like

```
[*.ts]
export class Test{
      test: string;
      constructor(foo: string){
        this.test = foo;
      }
}
```

I now want to create several test-objects and push them to an array

```
[*.ts]
arr = [];
arr.push(new Test("dummy"));
arr.push(new Test("dummy2"));
```

In the html part, I now want to loop over the test array and access the 'test'-variable:

```
  [*.html]
  <item  *ngFor="let i of arr">
        {{i.test}}
  </item>
```

But this seems not to work. For people familiar with typescript this should be obvious, for me however it is not. Do you get what I want to do and do you have any advice?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I think you are conflating things here... There is no "looping" in HTML, this is something that frameworks provide for you. `*ngFor` is an Angular thing. Are you using Angular and TypeScript, is that it? If so, you should tag this as Angular.

Comment: Actually you are right. I use angular and typescript. It is kind of confusing all this different frameworks and languages... sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing the objects to wrong variable, It should be,

```
arr = [];
arr.push(new Test("dummy"));
arr.push(new Test("dummy2"));
```